# Error Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter' not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

After i install composer require
there some error
Generating optimized autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

Error

Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter' not found

at C:\laragon\www\iqbalchandra-bwaStore\app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php:59
55|      * @return void
56|      */
57|     protected function configureRateLimiting()
58|     {

> 59|         RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
> 60|             return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
> 61|         });
> 62|     }
> 63| }

1   C:\laragon\www\iqbalchandra-bwaStore\app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php:38
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::configureRateLimiting()

2   C:\laragon\www\iqbalchandra-bwaStore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot()
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

i dont know how to fix it

Comment: What do you mean by "install composer require"? Which command did you run? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

At app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php add to file top:

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;` in your app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php class.

I had the same problem when upgrading from laravel 7 to laravel 8. This article helped. https://www.amitmerchant.com/new-ratelimiter-facade-in-laravel-8/